# Execute javascript code in last when page unloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have two pages on first page there is form once user finishes with the form he will click on submit button after that first page code unloading will start and user will be redirected on second page

**Actual(problem)**

Loading icon is coming but after some time it's getting close due to page unloading because user is getting redirected on second page

**Expected**

Loading icon should appear until user is not redirected completely

**I have tried with [unload](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_unload.asp) but it;s deprecated is there anything similar to unload**

Comment: It would help to see your code, but I assume you mean that the loading icon stops animating, or disappears when the page unloads. This is standard behaviour as the current DOM is removed from memory, ready to load the next page. There is nothing you can do about this. If you do not want this behaviour, you will need to implement your site as a Single Page Application (SPA). However you should note that this is a major architectural change and not a simple task.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you got my point. there is no way to do this?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  is setInterval will work  here ?

Comment: No. As I said above, there is no workarounds for this. It's how the page works. You cannot display something that is not in memory

Answer (score 0):

You can use beforeUnload event but I'm not sure if I understand completely your problem and I don't know if it what you want. With this event the user receive a prompt asking if he is sure about leaving the page

Comment: Acutally i want to do  the action afterunload is there anything like afterunload ?

Comment: The problem is that the browser stops new executions on unload and the only way to do something (the problem is the prompt) is do it before